# Get current working directory in Completer in binary PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

I am working on an existing binary PowerShell module in .NET 6. I need to add a new parameter `ConfigurationName` to a cmdlet name. The cmdlet looks something like this:

```
public ReaderCmdlet : Cmdlet
{

  [Parameter]
  public string ProjectFolder { get; set; }

  ...

}
```

My new parameter is called `ConfigurationName` and should have a completer that allows me to suggest possible values. I would define it like so:

```
[Parameter]
[ArgumentCompleter(typeof(ConfigurationCompleter))]
public string ConfigurationName { get; set; }
```

And this is my completer:

```
public class ConfigurationCompleter : IArgumentCompleter
{

  public IEnumerable<CompletionResult> CompleteArgument(
      string commandName,
      string parameterName,
      string wordToComplete,
      CommandAst commandAst,
      IDictionary fakeBoundParameters)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

The problem now is, that my new parameter depends on the existing parameter `ProjectFolder` in a sense that it's completion results are read from the project indicated by `ProjectFolder`. If the user specifies a fully qualified path, it's not a problem, because i can access the parameter using `fakeBoundParameters`.

But if the user specifies a relative project folder, I would need to resolve this relative folder using the current working directory of PowerShell. While this info is easily retrievable from within a Cmdlet itself (using `SessionState.Path`), I cannot find a method of doing the same from inside the completer, which runs without any cmdlet context.

I already tried to sneak my way into a `SessionState` by using `Runspace.DefaultRunspace.SessionStateProxy.Path`, but (apart from being unsure how reliable that is) accessing it throws an exception that there's already a pipeline running (for the completion itself I assume) and as such I cannot use it.

Any ideas? The default PS completer somehow is able to do so. I mean the one that starts when no other completer is defined and just suggests the list of files in the current directory.